# How to change which server I have Azure AD Connect runs on?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I currently have Azure AD Connect running on a server that I'm getting ready to decommission. I'd like to transition the app to another server to do the syncing to Azure AD. What's the proper war to do this? Can I just reinstall the app, log in with the current creds and proceed as is, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD connect Staging mode can be used for introducing a new server and decommission the old:

[Azure AD Connect sync: Operational tasks and consideration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-operations)

The detailed steps to migrate Azure AD Connect to a new server are:

1. Review the configuration of the existing Azure AD Connect instance
2. Install the new Azure AD Connect instance in staging mode
3. Compare configurations of the old and new servers
4. Swtich-over synchronization to the new server
5. Decommission the old server

Reference document [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/47886f3d-108c-4010-af8e-ebe57f8449af/migrating-azure-ad-connect-to-new-server).